# To upload an excel file as a clob

Tags: excel, jdbc, clob

Could some one give an idea about how to convert an excel file into a CLOB in oracle through JDBC. I would like to know how to covert excel file into a String using API available as part of JDK and the conversion from string to clob should be straight forward. Thanks in advance. If a similar question was already raised, kindly provide me the link.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Oracle besides the destination? Would the question be the same if the destination was MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a library out side of the standard java api to read a binary excel document.

You could use the [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to read in the Excel document then create a CSV String as you read in the document.

If you don't want to use an outside library then I would change the field type to blob and use the setBlob method of java.sql.PreparedStatment passing it a FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to parse the data (read the contents) you can use a library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

If you want to use the only standard API, then save the excel as CSV file and process the file as a comma seperated value list. That can easily be done with readline to read each line and split that line to values using the split method on a String.

If you do not need to parse data you should stream the data directly from file to a CLOB and not first transform the excel to a String
An example can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/files/advanced/LOBSample/LOBSample.java.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the representation of a spreadsheet in text format? The values indented by tabs? The formulas? What if you have more than one page in the xls file?

If what you really whant to do is to store the file in the database use a BLOB and store it as bytes.